# How to make grouped labels of <mat-select> sticky to top when scroll down in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have list that group items under multiple headings. As you scroll through the list, the current title or heading follows you until you reach the next one at which point the current one is pushed up and the new title or heading docks to the top.

```
<mat-select (openedChange)="detectOpen($event)">
<mat-optgroup label="A">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
<mat-optgroup label="B">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
<mat-optgroup label="C">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
<mat-optgroup label="D">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
<mat-optgroup label="E">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add this css class into your main css file :

```
  mat-optgroup.sticky{
        label{
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 1; // appear above mat-option
            top: 0; // fix at the top
            background-color: white; // don't see mat-option when scrolling
            box-shadow: 1px -2px 10px 0px grey; // shadow at the bottom
        }
    }
```

Then add this to your `mat-optgroup` : `class="sticky"`